# Installing MDM to replace GDM?

Tags: mint, display-manager

I had downloaded the MDM deb file from the following link. [`http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mdm/mdm_1.0.4_i386.deb`](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mdm/mdm_1.0.4_i386.deb)

But when I'm installing through the `GDebi` package manager, it shows me this error.

[image: MDM ERROR]

It doesn't state anything. Recently I've switched from `lightDM` to `GDM`

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: ...remove gdm. There is no need for two login managers.

Comment: I am interested in knowing how mdm works out. Please consider adding the information here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX

Comment: @mikewhatever I could switch between `lightDM` and `GDM` and both are installed. But this happens only with `MDM`

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt-get remove gdm`

`sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file`

Be aware that because you are installing this deb from a file and from another repository that you may have to pull in other dependencies from Mint. Those new dependencies may break stuff in Ubuntu as well. But, honestly, as Mint is Ubuntu-based I don't see that happening. Just wanted to warn you in advance so you know what you're getting yourself into.

Also, as you probably know, since you're installing from a file you'll have to manually update the packages/dependencies.